# Magento 2: Mailchimp Ecommerce Configuration

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

Has anyone any idea about the use of E-commerce Configuration in MailChimp for Magento 2? https://prnt.sc/no95d5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in Admin panel >> MailChimp  Menu there.

There is Mailchimp Stores link.

you need to click this link.

for more info related to e-commerce:-
https://mailchimp.com/resources/mailchimp-e-commerce/

Comment: i know where is this setting, i just want to know what is a use of that ?

Comment: @Camit1dk answer updated